# Запретить индексацию

Tags: веб-программирование, индексация

Есть ли на сегодня реально работающий способ запретить индексацию страниц поисковыми машинами вроде гугла кроме robots.txt, который не будет работать если юзеру доступен только каталог на сервере (~username)?

Comment: `robots.txt` реально не работает. Роботы все равно просматривают содержимое.

Comment: @Visman ну гугл и ко вроде как придерживаются его.

Comment: этот файл всего-лишь пожелание от владельца сайта для поисковых роботов. Они не обязаны это пожелание выполнять. Если хотите скрыть контент от роботов, скрывайте его от всех гостей и показывайте только тем, кто авторизовался на сайте.